# Rounding float (Single) numbers in C#

Tags: c#, math, rounding

I understand that in-memory representation of floating numbers assumes that numbers are not exact, however this was much surprise to me that we can potentially get a quite significant error when we performing rounding (note that float numbers are expected to have precision of 7 and rounding is to 5)

```
?Math.Round(0.149705F, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

0.1497

while it is perfectly OK with double

```
?Math.Round(0.149705, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

0.14971

and it is also perfect

```
?Math.Round((decimal)0.149705F, 5, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

So because I have to use float numbers returned from some legacy code and I need to round it exactly as it was rounded in some legacy application (COBOL) which was rounding this value to 0.14971, I applied something like this

```
 ?System.Math.Round(0.149705F + 0.00000001F, 5, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Do you know a better solution?

Comment: Better solution: 1: Read [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). 2,. find out what rounding the legacy application used (bankers, to zero, ...?). 3. Implement matching operation (or tell your users it is not possible: single precision storage may have already lost too much information).

Comment: 'that float numbers are expected to have precision of 7' this information is totally false, any source? :P\

Comment: The precision of 7 digits is only applicable reliably to the integer part. The fractional part will almost always contain some noise. The number represented by `0.149705F` is actually the number `0.1497049927711...`. So you see where the problem lies. If that is all you can get out of your system, there is nothing you can do as Richard already told you.

Comment: if you need "exact" the same way of rounding use `single precision float` for this  or try to set mantisa bits unused in float to zeroes (done by single AND operation). The approach with constant addition you proposed is wrong and will not work for any numbers just for some...